# Find-As-You-Type Dropdown not eliminating answers

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a find-as-you-type dropdown, but as answers get eliminated, they're still taking up space and pushing down the correct matching results. What am I doing wrong?

JS:

```
<script>
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

<script>

/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

/* Function for search filtering in player list*/
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}


</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you try to debug your code in order to get more information about this issue?

Comment: Display none shouldn't keep the space, are the links in a li with a height/padding/margin? Is something overwriting the display none with !important?

Comment: @lamonde the links aren't in a li at all - are they supposed to be?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes i'm not seeing anything at first glance, but still looking!